# Unable to run Xamarin Forms Cross Platform Application on an external android device

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to run my app on my Galaxy Tab A. But it does not seem to appear as an option on Visual Studio. I have tried a lot of solutions and I do not know what else I can do.

My Tablet settings
[image: 1]

**This is my VS version** :
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.10.20 (build 0)

Please, if anyone can help me out, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Did you enable debugging and development on your Galaxy Tab A .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

Comment: I have already enabled Developer Mode and switched on USB Debugging. It still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few things you might like to try:

- change the cable
- maybe try a different USB port, there were some with similar issues that had issues with USB3 and or non powered hubs
- Toggle on/off for 'USB Debugging' in settings
- try restarting adb (the devices list in VSM - "refresh"), or `adb kill-server`
- restart the machine